# How do I force the urls in my references to wrap at the end of the line?

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the `small caption` for my images is not working well. In source code it looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{algorithm.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \centering
          \caption[\protect\url{https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Enigma-action.svg}]{Jak funguje Enigma}
  \label{fig:algorithm}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I think this is ugly on one hand and not the right place to put the urls on the other. Add it *after* the caption: `Source: \url{wikipedia.org}`. If you want, you can define a simple macro that places the word *Source* for you. That way, you know where a picture is taken from without looking it up in a list far away from the current point of reading.

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you.

- Redefine `\url` to take advantage of linebreaking in the `\path`
  macro
- Omit the "`http://`" in the url you write
- Also see the MWE for proper use of `\centering`

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe,text={3in,4in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[pdftex,breaklinks,debug]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\url}[1]{%
\href{http://#1}{\path{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
%    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{algorithm.jpg}
xxxx
\caption[\protect\url{upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Enigma-action.svg}]{Jak funguje Enigma}
  \label{fig:algorithm}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - though untested:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Could add some context: where is this line of text supposed to go? Presumably in the preamble?

Comment: yes, sorry Seamus.